# How to create a unique name in a dataframe for similar strings?

Tags: r, string, function, dataframe

This is my current dataset.

```
persons<- c("James", "Michael", "Michael", "Robert", "Richard", "Harry", "Harry", "Ben", "Michael", "Harry")
```

Since the names here are common. I want to make every name unique.
To do this I used this set of code:

```
unique<- function(vec)
{
  sub('[.]',':',make.names(persons,unique = TRUE))
}
Strings<- unique(vec)
```

I got my desired output. But I want to have the same kind of result by using strsplit() and paste() function. Also I want to use collapse parameter of paste function.

```
My desired output:
James
Michael
Michael:1
Robert
Richard
Harry
Harry:1
Ben
Michael:2
Harry:2
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is here. So you have code that works fine, but you want to use different functions for some reason? That doesn't make any sense. Why do you need to use those different functions?

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks for the info. I have already voted for the answers that answered my questions. Plus I asked this question because I want to do the same thing in a different way. Because I want to learn how can we use different codes for doing the same thing.

Comment: The function you currently have is just `make.unique(persons, sep=":")` too.

Comment: @thelatemail, can't we do this by using strsplit and paste function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will accomplish the task:

```
sapply( strsplit( make.names(persons, unique = TRUE), split="[.]") , paste, collapse=":")


[1] "James"     "Michael"   "Michael:1" "Robert"    "Richard"   "Harry"    
 [7] "Harry:1"   "Ben"       "Michael:2" "Harry:2"
```

The "tricks" are a) recognizing that using `split="."` inside `strsplit` will fail because the period is a regex wildcard, and b) learning to use the `collapse` parameter for `paste` to ligate items in a list item..